# 504 Gateway Timeout Error appears in selenium grid

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Python:** 3.10.8

**Selenium server:** 4.14.0

**Java:** 11.0.19

**Python Selenium:** 4.14.0

I am getting a "**504 Gateway timeout**" error while running the sample code given below. Could someone assist me here please?

Note: Both Hub and Node machines are in same network.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\foo\Automation\boo\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=URI, options=webdriver.EdgeOptions())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head>
<body><h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
<p>Server error - server 00.00.000.111 is unreachable at this moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></p>
<!--Zscaler/6.2--></body></html>
```

**Sample program:-**

```
from selenium import webdriver

URI = 'http://00.00.000.111:4444/wb/hub'
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=URI, options=webdriver.EdgeOptions())
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

**Hub Logs:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Selenium\selenium_4.14.0>java -jar selenium-server-4.14.0.jar hub
11:58:10.430 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
11:58:10.446 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
11:58:10.649 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://00.000.000.111:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://00.000.000.111:4443]
11:58:10.696 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://00.000.000.111:4442 and tcp://00.000.000.111:4443
11:58:10.727 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
11:58:11.743 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
11:58:12.477 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.14.0 (revision e5a96349ce): http://00.000.000.111:4444
11:58:31.025 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
11:58:31.338 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node 808d5167-18da-4dff-a247-18905743af3d (uri: http://00.00.00.22:5555) from DOWN to UP
11:58:31.338 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 808d5167-18da-4dff-a247-18905743af3d at http://00.00.00.22:5555. Health check every 120s
```

**Node Logs:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Selenium\selenium_4.14.0>java -jar selenium-server-4.14.0.jar node --publish-events tcp://00.000.000.111:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://00.000.000.111:4443 --max-sessions 1
11:58:07.749 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
11:58:07.749 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
11:58:07.921 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://00.000.000.111:4442 and tcp://00.000.000.111:4443
11:58:07.983 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
11:58:08.999 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
11:58:09.139 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://00.00.00.22:5555
11:58:09.264 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 8 available processors
11:58:09.264 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Looking for existing drivers on the PATH.
11:58:09.264 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Add '--selenium-manager true' to the startup command to setup drivers automatically.
11:58:09.952 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - Unable to discover proper chromedriver version in offline mode
11:58:10.327 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - Exception managing MicrosoftEdge: Unable to discover proper msedgedriver version in offline mode
11:58:10.577 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - Unable to discover proper geckodriver version in offline mode
11:58:10.827 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - Unable to discover proper IEDriverServer version in offline mode
11:58:10.843 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Edge for {"browserName": "MicrosoftEdge","platformName": "Windows 10"} 1 times
11:58:10.858 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
11:58:11.093 INFO [NodeServer$1.start] - Starting registration process for Node http://00.00.00.22:5555
11:58:11.108 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.14.0 (revision e5a96349ce): http://00.00.00.22:5555
11:58:11.108 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
11:58:11.468 INFO [NodeServer.lambda$createHandlers$2] - Node has been added
```